# After call onBackPressed ViewGroup is not visible

Tags: java, android

When I call onBackPressed () elsewhere, the layout disappears in post runnable. It is not visible. Why is this happening? Is it possible to detect this in the fragment and call layout in runnable it again?

In fragment initViews:

```java
private ViewGroup layout_joystick;
...
layout_joystick.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        joyStick = new JoyStick(context, layout_joystick, R.drawable.stick);
        joyStick.setLayoutSize(layout_joystick.getWidth(), layout_joystick.getHeight());   
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem whether it is in `onBackPressed` or in `Runnable` ?

Comment: Problem occurs when onBackPressed is called, layout in runnable disappears.